# jQuery blocked for site hosted from dropbox

Tags: jquery, dropbox, vs-web-site-project

Often, if i'm working on a simple website to show someone, i'll host it in the public folder of my dropbox site and send them a link to the public URL.

Today I did this with a site using jQuery and it wouldn't work.  Turned out that jQuery was being blocked when loaded from code.jQuery.com.  I changed it so that jQuery loaded from the google api site instead and it all worked fine.

Not sure if this is a typical problem or am I doing something wrong?\

Comment: dropbox has started blocking jquery, as far as i have seen

Answer (score 0):

dropbox may put blocks in place so that people don't host sites or something like that ... you could prob just pull down the file and reference it locally to make sure that in the future google api site isn't blocked in the future...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine how Dropbox could influence whether or not your browser would download something from `code.jquery.com`, nor can I think of a reason why it would. (I work at Dropbox but have no personal knowledge of this.)

So I suspect there's something else wrong. Perhaps if you could share a link to something that's not working, people could help debug.

Answer (score 0):

when you refer to another page use `//` without `http` or `https` specifier.

for example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Check out [this](http://infoheap.com/how-to-use-dropbox-as-mini-webserver/) example.